# SlickDart component using AngularDart Error

Tags: dart, slickgrid, angular-dart

I am currently trying to set an AngularDart component which receives data from a parent component and draws a SlickDart grid with it. The problem is that it throws the following error:
[image]

The code for it is:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div id="grid" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
</div>

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:slickdart/slick.dart' as grid;
import 'package:slickdart/src/slick_custom.dart';
import 'package:slickdart/src/slick_editor.dart'; //new SelectListEditor

@Component(
  selector: 'slick-grid',
  styleUrls: const ['slickGrid_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'slickGrid_component.html',
  directives: const [],

)

class SlickGridComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  Map data;

  ngOnInit() {
    grid.SlickGrid n=init(data);
    n.init();
  }

  grid.SlickGrid init(passedData){
    Element el = querySelector('#grid');
    Map opt = {
      'explicitInitialization': false,
      'multiColumnSort': false,
      'frozenColumn': 0,
      'frozenRow': 1,
      'editable': true
    };

    List columns = new grid.ColumnList.fromMap(passedData["fields"]);
    List gridData = passedData["data"];
    grid.SlickGrid sg= new grid.SlickGrid(el, gridData, columns, opt);
    return sg;
  }

 }
```